# Slow laggy Javafx-Performance on Retina Display

Tags: java, javafx, retina

I have a simple method which writes pixels to a canvas' GrapicConte2D. A int[]-pixelarray is getting randomized every frame and updated with the PixelWriters setPixels()-Method.

I have a Dual-Monitor-setup, a "regular" screen and a macbook pro retina. When dragging my application frame into my "regular" screen everything works very fine for me. But placing it on my MacBooks Retina Displays it gets really laggy.

I have really no idea what went wrong. I was checking my code a few times, but it seems that I cannot help myself.

I would be very grateful for every advise that could help me.

Thanks

Code:

```
public class CanvasTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Random random = new Random();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1280, 800);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        PixelWriter writer = gc.getPixelWriter();
        PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance();

        int[] pixels = new int[(int) (canvas.getWidth() * canvas.getHeight())];



        scrollPane.setContent(canvas);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
                    pixels[i] = (255 << 24) | random.nextInt(0xffffff);
                }


                writer.setPixels(0, 0, (int) canvas.getWidth(), (int) canvas.getHeight(),
                        format, pixels, 0, (int) canvas.getWidth());
            }
        };

        root.setCenter(scrollPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,1280,800));
        primaryStage.show();

        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code? That would help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I posted an excerpt of my code, but I am not sure if it helps, it is very simple. It takes place in my Canvas' constructor. And my canvas is layouted into a BorderPane..

Comment: Well, I'm guessing your retina display is very high resolution, so this code is going to run slower than a normal display. And depending on how often your handle() method is called by the AnimationTimer, then this could start to get very laggy indeed. Especially given the 3 calls to Random.nextInt() in there happening for every pixel, every frame. That's a heap of processing going on there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know, my code is not very smart and should be optimized. I am just wondering why it runs much slower on my retina screen.  Right know it seems that loading the Canvas-object into my scrollPane slows it down. When i take my canvas out of the scollPane it runs as fast as on my regular monitor.

Comment: You might want to [try a different pixel format](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2436712) with your application and see if it makes a difference, for instance try [byteBgraPre](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelFormat.html#getByteBgraPreInstance--).  The reasoning being that if you are writing pixels in the format that the underlying graphics system uses natively, then there is less work for the graphics system to do to get the pixels into the correct format.

Comment: I tried all five PixelFormats but with the the IntArgbInstance (and IntPre) I had the highest FPS. I know, maybe my approach is not the best, but I really do not know what else I could do.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your Retina display has more pixels total and a higher pixel density and therefore more calculations have to be done per frame. If you are not set on using the `GraphicsContext2D`, I would look into OpenGL.

If you still want to use the `GraphicsContext2D`, I would take less sample of randomness to make it less laggy. Instead of finding a random value for every pixel, you could find a random value for every other pixel, and just set the nearby pixels to that color as well. It would look slightly worse, but it would reduce lag. Again, OpenGL uses GPU rendering and will be much faster.

Try this instead:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y+=2) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x+=2) {
        int i = x + y * width;
        screen[i] = (255 << 24) | (random.nextInt(256) << 16) | (random.nextInt(256) << 8) | random.nextInt(256);
        screen[i+1] = screen[i]; // The pixel just to the right of the current one
        screen[i+width] = screen[i]; // The pixel just below the current one
        screen[i+width+1] = screen[i]; // The pixel one to the right and one below this one
    }
}
```

**Note:** This will only work when the width and height are divisible by 2. That is why in this case, with many pixels, it is much easier to use the GPU instead.

Comment: Thank you Jermey for your response. It is a nice idea, but I think my problem is not the fact of rendering pixels but it is my unefficient usage of the components. Take a look at my updated code. I think it is because of the scrollPane. It slows my application down, when i load a canvas into it.