# Is changing the resolution of only one particular component in JavaFX possible?

Tags: java, javafx, components, resolution

is it possible to change the resolution for only one component(in my case ImageView or Canvas) in a JavaFX-Application to save resources?

Greetings

Comment: What do you mean "change the resolution"?  What resources do you expect to save?

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for my inaccurate formulation. I work on a Retina Display and want to render pixels with a "regular" resolution. I have HiDPI by default, which I can change by setting allowhidpi to false, but is it also to change the dpi for only one particular component?

Comment: This seems a bit like an [X-Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) based upon your progress with [Slow laggy Javafx-Performance on Retina Display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362075/slow-laggy-javafx-performance-on-retina-display), which could be due to the pixel format you are using and not primarily related to HiDPI resolutions.